# Overloading operators using pointers or objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class named Complex with many member methods returning objects of that Complex class, and many member methods taking objects of class Complex as parameter.

```
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex sampleFunc(Complex c) { ... }
    Complex operator+(Complex c) { ... }
};
```

This would be a library, so other users would be using my class. Since, most users use:

```
Complex *ptrObj = new Complex();    // declaration 1
```

rather than using:

```
Complex obj;                        // declaration 2
```

The code I have written above would work with declaration 2 but not with declaration 1. I can change the prototype for sampleFunc() as follows:

```
Complex* sampleFunc(Complex *c) { ... }
```

But then I cannot meaningfully change the operator+() function to get the effect of adding two objects (rather than erroneously adding two pointers). So, what API should I be exposing - that works with declaration 1 or that works with declaration 2 or should I provide two versions for each function? I believe that passing pointers to functions would work faster, but then operator overloading would be a problem.

Comment: If they're allocated dynamically and then stored somewhere and then accessed via references, then your overloads will work fine.  You cannot overload operators on pointer types.

Comment: What is the actual meaning of your class?  How large is one instance of it?

Comment: My class has a character array whose length can vary from a few characters to thousands of characters. No other data members exist, but the class contains a large number of functions (about 60+)

Comment: @user1637645: What is `sizeof(Complex)`?

Comment: sizeof(Complex) = sizeof(char*) + sizeof(int) + functions...

Comment: "*I cannot meaningfully change the operator+() function to get the effect of adding two objects (rather than erroneously adding two pointers)*" - if users decide to allocate your objects with `new`, they will have to dereference the pointers when calling your operations, eg: `Complex *c1 = new Complex; Complex *c2 = new Complex; Complex c3 = *c1 + *c2;` That is just the way C++ works. Don't define your operations to expect pointers as input, only (references to) object instances.

Comment: Pointers would speed up every function call. e.g. Java internally uses pointers everywhere. But then dereferencing them would take away the elegance of operator overloading. Is there a middle way? @RemyLebeau do you mean that I should define it as Complex& sampleFunc(Complex &c) ?

Comment: @user1637645 use references instead of pointers whenever possible. The speed of pointers without the dangers of pointing to invalid addresses or the inelegance of manual dereferencing. And if `sampleFunc()` does not modify `c` then use `const Complex &c` (or `Complex const &c`) instead of `Complex &c`. The return value should not be a `Complex&` reference if a new `Complex` is created, returning by value is the correct way.

Comment: @user1637645 *Since, most users use Complex *ptrObj = new Complex();*  -- Are most of your users Java programmers?  A C++ programmer who knows better will choose `Complex ptrObj;` over using `new` in most circumstances.  Using `new` to create objects has the earmarks of a Java programmer who does not understand C++ value semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described in the comments, your `Complex` class is basically a variable-length string, and contains a `char*` plus an `int`.

The first thing to do, then, is to discourage the users of this class from doing `new Complex`, because it is not efficient.  You are doing dynamic memory allocation within your class, so there is no need to do it outside as well (you're just adding more pointer indirection).

You should write your operators in the conventional way, which is to accept references, not pointers.  And users will typically not need to deal with pointers, because  your class abstracts the dynamic memory as an implementation detail.

For example:

```
class Complex
{
public:
    // TODO: define constructors and assignment operator

    Complex sampleFunc(Complex&); // could also return Complex& (*this)
    Complex operator+(const Complex&) const;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> _data;
    size_t _size;
};
```

Comment: Earlier, I had 2 constructors:  Complex(Complex *c) { ... } and Complex(Complex &c) {  .... // copy constructor ... }. Should I remove the first one (non-copy-constructor) now?

Comment: You should have just one copy constructor: `Complex(const Complex&)`.  Note the `const`, which all copy constructors should have.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you will often be better off avoiding pass by value, and specifying your member functions as accepting a reference

```
class Complex
{
  public:
     Complex sampleFunc(const Complex &c) { ... }
     Complex operator+(const Complex &c) { ... }
};
```

The `const` specifies that the function will not logically change `c` as far as the caller is concerned - which is often the same effect as passing by value, except that it does not create a copy of the object being passed.

Removing the `const` allows the object to be changed.

That said, you CAN pass by value to any function you like, if it makes sense to pass a copy of an object to a function rather than a reference.

Second, your preconceptions from using another language are showing, and leading you to a wrong conclusion about C++.  Specifically, your belief

> This would be a library, so other users would be using my class. Since, most users use:
>
> ```
> Complex *ptrObj = new Complex();    // declaration 1
> ```
>
> rather than using:
>
> ```
> Complex obj;                        // declaration 2
> ```

is false.   Most C++ developers, given these two choices, will default to using the second form since, in quite a few circumstances, the first form is poor practice in C++ - due to a requirement to `delete ptrObj` when done, in order to avoid a memory leak, and the potential to forget to do that, particularly in non-trivial code.

Using the code in a library does not change this.   As a rough rule (and, as a rough rule, there are some exceptions) if you find yourself writing lots of code that uses pointers in C++ (unless you are writing a version of the standard library) then your design is broken.